# Oozie Java Action fails during Ingestion with HCat?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, sqoop, hcatalog

I have a jar to perform data ingestion; it works when using `hadoop jar <jar_name> <args>` from the command line, but when I try to implement the same using Oozie Java Action, I get the error below.

Error Message:

```
While running Java Action during Sqoop Import 2017/02/23 13:02:36.848 [ERROR] main (ImportTool.java) - Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: HCat exited with status 1
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities.executeExternalHCatProgram(SqoopHCatUtilities.java:1196)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities.launchHCatCli(SqoopHCatUtilities.java:1145)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities.createHCatTable(SqoopHCatUtilities.java:679)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities.configureHCat(SqoopHCatUtilities.java:342)
```

Please let me know if you face similar issue during Sqoop ingestion.

Answer (score 1):

Could you verify all the dependent jars are available in hdfs along with the jar that you want to execute. This will be needed as Oozie will spawn 1 map only job to trigger the action and it can be executed on any  of the available nodes.  That node will try to access the jar and dependent files from HDFS.